# AWS Amplify Cloudflare custom route

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, dns, aws-amplify, cloudflare

I have a small react app that is hosted in AWS Amplify.
My domain is controlled by Cloudflare. I set up the DNS in it to point to AWS Amplify apps. It works fine with the domain and its subdomains.

But I want to have multiple apps on the main domain but with different route. For example

- domain.com/app1 -->
- domain.com/app2 -->

Is it possible to do using just DNS/Cloudflare/Amplify or I need a reverse proxy for it like nginx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Cloudflare paid account, you could use `Resolve Override` with Page Rules which allow you to resolve DNS differently for specific paths.

Example:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206190798-Using-Resolve-Override-in-Page-Rules

Or you can also write a Cloudflare worker to handle it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't find such settings in the Page Rules. It looks like the article is obsolete.

Comment: Are you using an enterprise account on cloudflare? probably the rule is only available for enterprise customers.

Comment: I'm on a free plan.

Comment: Unfortunately, the resolve override is not available for free plan users.